# Google Org Charts Display Functionality

Tags: google-visualization

I'm using Google Org charts and I need to have a child element have 3 parents above it - is this possible? For example a situation where an employee has three bosses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the parent column only accepts one id.  Which is lucky for the employee with 3 bosses because maybe it will help them sort out who the employee actually reports to.

As a conceptual work-around you could establish the three bosses as a single entity like "The Triumverate", "The Tribunal", or whatever and then put the employee under that entity.  Or have a node with 3 comma-seperated names like "Mike, John, Susan", and then use "Mike, John, Susan" as the parent node for the poor confused employee.

This is one case where, while I know these things happen, when you're formalizing this you should really be asking, "Why does this employee have 3 bosses?"  It's really very confusing for both the employees and the bosses 99% of the time. It is often best to pick one boss for them to report to and then have all the bosses communicate sideways to each other.  The only exception that I can think of is a shared receptionist somewhere like a Doctor's Office with multiple doctors.  And even then it might help for the receptionist to have one formal boss who has the right to discipline, fire, give them a raise, and two other superiors that just use their services. Helps a lot if the employee encounters conflicting orders.

But of course, that's not what you asked for.  But it is probably why they didn't make nodes support multiple parent nodes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and suggestions. Yes it is clear that having multiple parents is not possible.